# AngularJS datatable always showing No matching records found

Tags: angularjs, datatable, server-side-rendering

I've tried almost everything for past 5 days in my AngularJS datatable.

Here are the code snippets and outputs:

HTML

```
 <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table small">
 <thead>
     //Tried including tr, th too and without them too
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

In angularJS

```
 //Dt options
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                return json;
            },
            url: "/allserviceprovider",
            type: "POST"

        })
            .withOption('processing', true) //for show progress bar
            .withOption('serverSide', true) // for server side processing
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers') // for get full pagination options // first / last / prev / next and page numbers
            .withDisplayLength(10) // Page size
            .withOption('order', []) // for default sorting column // here 0 means first column
            //
            // .withOption('bJQueryUI', true);

        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('merchantName').withTitle('Merchant Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('serviceProviderName').withTitle('Service Provider')
        ];
```

Output from Server side

```
{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 2, recordsFiltered: 2, data: Array(2)}
data: Array(2)
   0: (2) ["abc provider", "some name"]
   1: (2) ["Operator Merchant", "operator_unique"]
length: 2
draw: 1
recordsFiltered: 2
recordsTotal: 2
```

Copied from chrome debugger (Not a RAW JSON)

I'm certain that this data is correct enough for being rendered by datatable, I've tried returning array of array and array of objects too in `data` But still no luck. what's might be going wrong? Please help me, I've been stuck for 5 days on this.

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: @MayankVadiya I am not getting any errors.. It just shows no matching records found in the table.